# List of methods and parameters available to Django's class based views?

Tags: python, django

I read the documentation and its kind of vague when it comes to outlining the methods/parameters/properties available to Class based views, is there a list of some website that provides such as list anywhere?

Answer (score 2):

You could look at the source code of the `View` classes:

- [View](https://github.com/django/django/blob/master/django/views/generic/base.py#L27)
- [TemplateView](https://github.com/django/django/blob/master/django/views/generic/base.py#L144)
- [RedirectView](https://github.com/django/django/blob/master/django/views/generic/base.py#L154)

Answer (score 1):

You should use your `python manage.py shell` and simply import your views and 
use `dir(my_view)` and `help(my_view)`

Answer (score 0):

You can use `python manage.py shell` and import the views you want and then use `dir()` for example, `dir(TemplateView)` or you can read the source code or you use `help()` method to give quick overview. For example, `help(TemplateView)`

Answer (score 0):

I find the website [Classy Class-based Views](http://ccbv.co.uk/) very useful. It also shows the inheritance order, class-hierarchy and much more.